# Blackberry - getLocation() method cannot be called from event thread

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gps, jsr179

I want to get the longitude and latitude of device. I used location api to get the longtitude and latitude the problem now I am facing is that I could not call the `getLocation()` method  inside button click event. It throws an error as `getLocation()` method cannot be called from event thread.Can any one tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply create another thread and call getLocation() from that thread. See the documentation for java.lang.Thread in the API documentation.